# monotouch - set current view

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a UISegmented control, which act as a tabs.
When a tab is clicked I wanted to change the view to another page.

Essentially at the moment I have two views each have their own segment control which switches from one view to the other and vice versa.

If I use PresentModalViewController I continually adding the view to the stack each time the user changes the uiSegment which isn't good.

I want to set the current view to a new view.
but at the same time ensure that if I call dismiss I can do back a view
My applicantion is structure like so:

[Main Window] --> [VC shows table of items] -->

```
                                   |--> [VC with Segment control  View 1]

                                   | (swap between)

                                   |--> [VC with Segment control  View 2]
```

so in both the views I would have for instance:

View1:

```
partial void Tabs_Changed (UISegmentedControl sender)
    {
        if( btnTabs.SelectedSegment == 1) {
            View2 view2 = new View2(); //load view 2
            this.PresentModalViewController(view2,false);
        }
    }
```

View 2:

```
partial void Tabs_Changed (UISegmentedControl sender)
    {
        if( btnTabs.SelectedSegment == 0) {
            View1 view1 = new View1(); //load view 1
            this.PresentModalViewController(view1,false);
        }
    }
```

But this is making the app unpredictable presumably cause I'm constantly stacking up views?

Please help.

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the PresentModalViewController() method really is not the way to go. You are indeed stacking multiple views which is a bad thing to do.

What I would do is have one view, with the UISegmentedControl and another 2 subviews added to it (use the AddSubview(View) method to do that).

On your viewDidLoad method, create the veiws and hide the second one using:

```
view1 = new UIView(){BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green}; 
view2 = new UIView(){Hidden = true, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red};
this.AddSubview(view1);
this.AddSubview(view2);
```

Now, in your method:

```
partial void Tabs_Changed (UISegmentedControl sender)
{
   bool v1Visible = btnTabs.SelectedSegment == 0);
   view1.Hidden = !v1Visible;
   view2.Hidden = v1Visible;     
}
```

I havent run the code, but it should work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. [switching between uiviewcontrollers without a UI navigator control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963175/switching-between-uiviewcontrollers-without-a-ui-navigator-control)

but doesnt need an UI to switch, call the App deletegate from your viewcontroller with
something like

```
var appDelegate = (AppDelegate) UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;              
appDelegate.switch();
```