# switching between uiviewcontrollers without a UI navigator control

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, switching

I want to switch between 2 UIViewController classes programmatically without any extra UI control like a UITabBarController that adds a UI to the application.

My main loads the first view controller with addSubView.

```
    vc1 = new viewc1();
    window.AddSubview(vc1.View);
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

I can load my second viewcontroller from the first one with PresentModalViewController

```
    vc2 = new viewc2();
    PresentModalViewController(vc2, true);
```

but i need to switch back and forth, and to release the old viewControllers to save memory.
What is the best way to do this? 
**DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(false);** in the 2nd view controller isnt releasing memory and I dont want modal "windows" as it doesnt seem optimal. I have a custom UI so the tabbar controller is not wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in simple code. But you can't release the view controllers as it required to handle user interactions such as button tap events etc. Adding a view to window will only preserve view instance. If you release your view controller instance, you could get a bad access error or unrecognized selector error.

So let your main code be

```
if(vc1==nil)
  vc1 = new viewC1();
window.addSubView(vc1.view);
window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

And your switch code will be

```
if(vc2==nil)
   vc2 = new viewC2();
if(vc1.view.superview!=nil){
   vc1.view.removefromSuperView();
   window.addsubview(vc2.view);
} else {
   vc2.view.removeFromSuperView();
   window.addsubview(vc1.view);
}
```

Now in dealloc method add

```
vc1.release();
vc2.release();
```

Thats it...Hope this helps...
I just followed your syntax

Comment: thanks. I used `code var appDelegate = (AppDelegate) UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
appDelegate.switch(); code` from the view controller to call my App delegate code. Looks like release() is unnecessary because of .net GC ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UINavigationController` still, you don't need the extra UI that it provides. You can use the .`Hidden` property of the `UINavigationBar` to hide that. To switch between views you can just use `PushViewController(controller, animated)` to push the new view. If you want to release the old controller then you can just set the `UINavigationController`'s `.ViewControllers` property using:

```
navigationController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[1]{ vc2 };
```

this will remove the reference of the first controller and make the second controller the root. (this will also work the other way around!)

Comment: nice to know. Its still a heavier component I suppose ,even with the UI hidden, than just adding directly to the main window.